# Chrome- Go back to previous webpage automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Is there a way to configure in `Chrome` (or any browser) that whenever a webpage changes it *automatically* goes back to the previous page.

E.g. If a user presses a **"Submit" button** on a survey, they will be shown the "finish" message *but then* the original webpage with the survey will load again?

Comment: I can't really find the utility of something like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go to previous page use

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
function initialize(){
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
alert("successfully submited");
setTimeout(goBack,2000)
});
function goBack(){
window.history.go(-1);
}
}
window.addEventListener("load",initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</body>
```

To go to a specific page

```
window.location = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not convinced it's a great idea, you know your requirements better than I do.

So to go back, you run this javascript.

```
window.history.back()
```

When you say immediately go back, I assume you want them to see the finish message first before being sent back after, say, 3 seconds?

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.history.back();
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

**Edit**

If you want to redirect without javascript, you can use a meta tag in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.example.com" />
```

So if you use server side rendering you could reference the `HTTP_REFERER` header and inject it into your meta tag.

If you don't use server side rendering (PHP, MVC, React, etc) and you can't use javascript, then no; you're stuffed.

Comment: Is there an option to do this in chrome, without adding JS?

Comment: See edit. You either need javascript, a specific url to go back to, or access to the HTTP_REFERER header

Comment: Is it possible to do this without altering any code, I.e. in an option within chrome/any browswer or a plugin etc?

Comment: I've no idea. There's two examples for you above and you keep asking for alternatives. I'm all out.

Comment: Ok Any suggestions as to which site?